# D3 bar graph does not re-size correctly

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I need some help with scaling with D3.In my codepen I am attempting to create a graph with some retrieve GDP data.

The data is retrieved and displayed correctly, but when I attempt to scale the graph only one vertical bar is displayed.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Here is a link to project codepen:
https://codepen.io/henrycuffy/pen/gKVdgv

The main.js:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON(
        'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/freeCodeCamp/ProjectReferenceData/master/GDP-data.json',
            function(data) {
            const dataset = data.data;

            const w = 1000;
            const h = 500;

            var maxX = d3.max(dataset, d => d[1]);
            var minDate = new Date(dataset[0][0]);
            var maxDate = new Date(dataset[dataset.length - 1][0]);

            var xScale = d3
                .scaleTime()
                .domain([minDate, maxDate])
                .range([0, w]);

            var yScale = d3
                .scaleLinear()
                .domain([0, maxX])
                .range([h, 0]);

            var xAxis = d3.axisBottom().scale(xScale);

            var yAxis = d3.axisLeft().scale(yScale);

            const svg = d3
                .select('body')
                .append('svg')
                .attr('width', w)
                .attr('height', h);

            svg
                .selectAll('rect')
                .data(dataset)
                .enter()
                .append('rect')
                .attr('x', (d, i) => xScale(i * 10))
                .attr('y', d => h - yScale(d[1]))
                .attr('width', 2)
                .attr('height', d => yScale(d[1]))
                .attr('fill', 'navy');
        }
    );
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a time scale for the x axis. But you aren't positioning the bars based on a time:

```
.attr('x', (d, i) => xScale(i * 10))
```

You are positioning each bar based on its index. The scale expects you to feed a date to it (it is taking the provided number and treating it as a date, which is pretty near the beginning of the epoch (Jan 1, 1970), which explains the positioning. The bars appear as one because each one is placed 10 milliseconds out from the previous one on a scale that covers decades, an imperceptible difference).

Instead let's feed the x scale the date in the data:

```
.attr('x', d => xScale(new Date(d[0]) )
```

Since the datum contains a string representation of the date, I'm converting to a date object here. You could do this to the data once it is loaded, but to minimize changes I'm just doing it when assigning the x attribute.

Here's an updated [plunkr](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vroMbR).

Comment: Thanks Andrew, your recommendation works. Also, thanks for the explanation.